# passing hadoop jobConf to streaming application using xml?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I've been playing around with hadoop streaming using c#. I've gotten most things working rather well, however there is one final thing I can't seem to find any documentation on.

I would like to pass jobconf variables to the streaming application. I know this can be done by passing them as -jobconf arguments from [here](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopStreaming), however using this for more complex job configurations would be rather hacky. I did, however, find that there exists in some form, a [jobconf xml](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/JobConfFile). Other than it's existence, I have found no mention of how it is used.

I was wondering if there was a way to pass such an xml into the hadoop streamer instead of passing numerous jobconf variables.

Comment: What version of hadoop are you using?

Comment: I'm on 2.7.3. Is the method different for different versions of hadoop?